# Separate different image names in JSON depending of text instances on this images

Tags: python, json, h5py

. Hi, does someone can help me with this problem. Here is code for generating coordinates of bounding box in JSON file. I'm generating images with text on it. So now in JSON file I need to write text instance with corresponding images.

You can see this problem on this picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ0Pl.png)
The word `couch` is on `clouds_125.jpg_0`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bVbR.png)
But the word `proof` is `on kerala_25.jpg_0`

If I generate 5 images with text then will be 5 names of images in the same gt_[ ]. I just want to separate image names depending of what text instances is on it.

So what I need is this format:

```
“gt_1”:  [   {“points”: [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], …, [xn, yn]], “transcription” : “trans1”, “language” : “Latin”, "illegibility": false },
                …
             {“points”: [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], …, [xn, yn]], “transcription” : “trans2”, “language” : “Chinese”, "illegibility": false }],

“gt_2”:  [
             {“points”: [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], …, [xn, yn]] , “transcription” : “trans3”, “language” : “Latin”, "illegibility": false }],

……
```

Here is code for generating coordinates of bounding box in JSON file. The results is stored in `Output.h5` file and from it JSON read data.

```
db = h5py.File('results/Output.h5', 'r')
dsets = sorted(db['data'].keys())
for k in dsets:
    db = get_data()
    imnames = sorted(db['data'].keys())

start = 0
coordinate = []
name = []
final = []
FinalFinal = [] 
for eachWord in textToList:
        length = len(eachWord)
        for i in range(0,4):
            for j in range(start,length+start):
                coordinate.append([charBB_list[0][0][i][j],
charBB_list[0][1][i][j]])
            name.append(coordinate)
            coordinate = []
        for j in range(0, length):
            for i in range(len(name)) :
                print(i,j, name[i][j]) ## koordinate da se snađem, treba
                final.append(name[i][j])

        with open("annotation.json") as json_file:
                    data=json.load(json_file)
                    temp=data["annotations"]
                    y = {
                        f'gt_{imnames}':
                            {
                        "transcription": eachWord,
                        "language": "Latin",
                        "illegibility": "False",
                        "points": [final]
                            }  
                        }
                    temp.append(y)
        
        write_json(data)
        finalToList = np.array(final)
        
        name=[]
        final = []
        start = len(eachWord) + start
```

I know that `imnames` variable contains all of names of generated images, but I don't know how to separate them.